# Stopping a delete on MySQL via Triggers

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers

I'm trying to intercept any DELETE commands against a particular table.  MySQL supports triggers but it doesn't seem to support a way to raise an error yet like SQL Server and other databases.

Can I do this with just an empty Trigger definition?  Something like:

```
create trigger trListsDelete on lists
instead of delete
as
begin
  /* Do nothing */
end
```

In SQL Server I could add a `RAISEERROR('You cannot delete lists.')` statement to force it to fail and that way I know the Delete wouldn't be executed.  Since MySQL doesn't support raising errors, how do I simply ignore the Delete command?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24/throw-error-in-mysql-trigger (raising error on update rather than delete).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique is you do something that will cause an error, such as update a column that doesn't exist.

Details here: [MySQL Triggers: How do you abort an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE with a trigger?](https://web.archive.org/web/20180330233216/http://www.brokenbuild.com/blog/2006/08/15/mysql-triggers-how-do-you-abort-an-insert-update-or-delete-with-a-trigger/)