# MySQL Trigger to prevent INSERT under certain conditions

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to make a trigger that will prevent the insertion if the birthdate (one of the columns) is in the future. I have this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo
BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.birthdate > CURRENT_DATE()
  THEN
    //How do I prevent the insert right here???
  END IF;
END;
```

How can I cancel the insert inside the if statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to abort INSERT operation in MySql trigger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538786/how-to-abort-insert-operation-in-mysql-trigger)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,99214,99300#msg-99300) I'm not sure if it's possible to do it that way.

> There's no support in MySQL's current
>   implementation of triggers to
>   voluntarily throw an exception and
>   abort the statement that spawned the
>   trigger.
>
> The workaround I've found is to write
>   a BEFORE trigger to set one of the
>   not-NULL columns in the table to NULL,
>   thus violating its NOT NULL
>   constraint. This causes the statement
>   that spawned the trigger to be
>   aborted.

Comment: Readers please note this statement is [no longer true.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22489342/1446005)

Answer (score 71):

### Example 1, MySQL, You can cancel that insert in the trigger with `signal sqlstate`

1. Create your table with a varchar column:

   ```
   mysql> create table yar (val VARCHAR(25) not null);
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
   ```
2. Create your 'before insert' trigger to check for a condition and disallow.

   ```
   mysql> delimiter $$
   mysql> create trigger foo before insert on yar
       -> for each row
       -> begin
       -> if new.val = '' then
       -> signal sqlstate '45000';
       -> end if;
       -> end;$$
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
   ```
3. Try to insert where the condition is met:

   ```
   mysql> delimiter ;

   mysql> insert into yar values("");
   ERROR 1644 (45000): Unhandled user-defined exception condition

   mysql> insert into yar values ("abc");
   Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

   mysql> select * from yar;
   +-----+
   | val |
   +-----+
   | abc |
   +-----+
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)
   ```

You inserted a blank string, the trigger saw it was blank and raised the signal to prevent the insert.

### Example 2, MySQL, Cancel the insert in the trigger by causing the data to violate a not null constraint.

1. Create your table with a varchar column:

   ```
   mysql> create table yar (val VARCHAR(25) not null);
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
   ```
2. Create your 'before insert' trigger to check for a condition and disallow.

   ```
   mysql> delimiter $$
   mysql> create trigger foo before insert on yar
       -> for each row
       -> begin
       -> if new.val = '' then
       -> set new.val = NULL;
       -> end if;
       -> end;$$
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
   ```
3. Try to insert where the condition is met:

   ```
   mysql> delimiter ;

   mysql> insert into yar values("");
   ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'val' cannot be null

   mysql> insert into yar values ("abc");
   Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

   mysql> select * from yar;
   +-----+
   | val |
   +-----+
   | abc |
   +-----+
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)
   ```

You inserted a blank string, the trigger saw it was blank and changed the value to null, so the insert is prevented.

Comment: This was life saver, would you clear my confusion.. in your "Example1.2"  what is the difference between  `if new.val = '' then`  and `if val = '' then` ?

Comment: If you want to have a text displayed you have to add "SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "your error text"" directly after signal sqlstate '45000': signal sqlstate '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "your error text"

Answer (score 21):

I don't know if it's to late but you can do that now :

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "your error text";
```

P.S. Don't forget to modify the delimiter before and after the trigger...

Comment: SIGNAL (sorry I forgot the S ... )

Comment: I struggled without this detail. Since when is this possible?

Answer (score 13):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER foo
BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.birthdate > CURRENT_DATE()
  THEN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Warning: birthdate can not be greater than current date!';
  END IF;

END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I created a table but there was no way to assign the minimum length of string in MySQL.  I created the table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
           (
             UserName varchar(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
             Password varchar(15) NOT NULL,
             Active Bool DEFAULT TRUE,
             CHECK (CHAR_LENGTH(UserName)>3)
           )
```

But the CHECK function doesn't work on insert.

So I changed my Table as follow :

```
CREATE TABLE Users
           (
             UserName varchar(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
             Password varchar(15) NOT NULL,
             Active Bool DEFAULT TRUE
           )
```

After that, create a Trigger:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
   BEFORE INSERT ON Users
   FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   IF CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.UserName) < 4 THEN
     DELETE FROM Users WHERE Users.UserName=NEW.UserName;
   END if;
 END$$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem described in the question sounds like a perfect candidate for a CHECK constraint - add this line to the table definition.

CONSTRAINT born_in_the_past CHECK (birthdate<=now())

Comment: That won't work - as the MySQL documentation says: "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines".