# Select from a table and insert to another table and deleting it from the source table

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a table named `tbl_requests` and `tbl_friends`, I know the query on how to SELECT a certain row from `tbl_requests` and INSERT it into `tbl_friends` by `ID`.

My problem now is how can I delete the row from `tbl_requests` automatically after selecting it and inserting it to `tbl_friends`.

Here is my query in `SELECT` from `tbl_requests` and `INSERT` to `tbl_friends`:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_friends 
     SELECT * 
       FROM tbl_requests 
      WHERE ID = 1
```

What will I add so that the row from `tbl_requests` will be deleted?

Comment: You could create your own stored procedure which would do both statements. I don't see any "straight sql way".

Comment: You could just have one table, with a flag indicating whether the request has been accepted.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff That's a good point!

Comment: yea it is @Gordon Linoff. I'll use a Boolean field as my flag. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at: [MySQL Trigger - delete after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189812/mysql-trigger-delete-after-update)

What you want is to trigger a delete after your insert.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
  AFTER INSERT
  ON  tbl_friends 
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM tbl_requests WHERE ID = new.id;
END
$$
```

Comment: I gave it a try on my own DB and worked... if it doesn't do tell :)

Comment: meewoK, since the OP originally mentioned being a newbie (prior to editing his post), it would help to point out the possible disadvantages along with using a trigger improperly.  I'm sure you could find more, but here's a list of a few.
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/24/sql-server-disadvantages-problems-of-triggers/

Comment: I see. thanks for that @Tiny Haitian. I already figured out the solution by using conditions in my php statements. But anyway, thanks to the both of you for the new ideas I just learned.

Comment: No problem.   Though there's nothing wrong with triggers (and they have their place), I just wanted to make sure you knew both sides of the story.   :)

Answer (score 1):

That can't be done in traditional sql with a single statement. The whole point of transactions is to do just that. Use

```
begin;
insert into tbl_friends (a,b,c) select u,v,w from tbl_requests where id = :myid;
delete from tbl_requests where id = :myid;
commit;
```

You may also use a trigger on the tbl_friends that deletes rows from tbl_requests where a new row is inserted.

Comment: i thought it's possible in just a single statement. well, tnx for giving me advice :)

Comment: @James: it is possible with a single statement - just not with MySQL