# create table constraint in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, constraints

I have a table in which I have some columns `a,b,c` and for each column there is another column ,say, `(x,y,z)` which is dependent on `a,b,c` respectively.

`x,y,z` will have value `1` if `a,b,c` has any value and will contain null if `a,b,c has null`.

For an example Lets say,
The values stored in `a` is `2` and `x` is the column dependent on it.
So `x` will have value as `1`.

If the values stored in `a` is `null` then  `x` will have value as `null`.

so is there a way in which we can declare this constraint  at the time of table creation.

Please suggest anything other than triggers.

Comment: guys thanks for responses, but please suggest any thing other than triggers, because I have read that we can put some constraints in  create table..

Comment: Nope, you cannot. Unlike most other DBMS (Postgre, Oracle, SQL Server...) MySQL does not support check constraints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the purpose of `x`, `y` and `z` is to simplify some queries then rather than having `x`, `y` and `z` as columns on your table you could also consider using a view to do this e.g.

```
create view myview as
  select a, b, c,
  if (isnull(a), null, 1) as x,
  if (isnull(b), null, 1) as y,
  if (isnull(c), null, 1) as z
  from mytable;
```

and then base your other queries on this view instead of directly on the table.

Comment: Hey  thanks for ur response, but in that table there are many places where the inserts take place, It is a huge application and we are having two different platforms...

Comment: Can you please elaborate the approach, or provide a reference of this this.

Comment: Hi. Which bit is unclear? The MySQL documentation on views is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/views.html).

Answer (score 4):

The constraint you are looking for is the check constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    a varchar(10),
    b varchar(10),
    c varchar(10),
    x integer,
    y integer,
    z integer,
    CONSTRAINT chk_X_Nulls CHECK ((a is null and x is null) or (a is not null and x = 1)),
    CONSTRAINT chk_Y_Nulls CHECK ((b is null and y is null) or (b is not null and y = 1)),
    CONSTRAINT chk_Z_Nulls CHECK ((c is null and z is null) or (c is not null and z = 1))
);
```

Unfortunately **this isn't implemented in MySQL**. There is an [open bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3464) dating back to 2004 for this feature so don't expect to see it any time soon.

Others have answered that you can use triggers or views to achieve the desired result, and these are the correct answers for MySQL.

You can also partially constrain your data using some simple tricks:

- Set the data type of `x, y, z` to `enum('1')`. This will prevent values other than `null` and `'1'` from being inserted but won't ensure the values are correct.
- If `a, b, c` have a limited range of possible values you can create foreign key constraints to other tables and populate those tables with every possible value of `a, b, c`
- You can create an [event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html) to update `x, y, z` on a schedule (eg once every hour or once a day). The values for `x, y, z` can be corrected if they wrong.

You can see the check constraint in action with PostGreSQL [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d2048)

If you need further advice please explain why triggers are inappropriate for your task.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't handle `CONSTRAINTS` per-se, but you could implement a similar behavior using a [`TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) on the `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` events. You will, however, have to rely on some other table-level constrains (`NOT NULL`) to get it working, as per [this other question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981930/mysql-trigger-to-prevent-insert-under-certain-conditions).

In your very specific case, it looks a lot like you would want to use the trigger to calculate the value of your `x, y, z` values in the trigger, rather than using it to prevent insertion of data with "improper" values - but your question does not make this point unambiguously clear, so it depends on what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) for this.

From the [Trigger syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) chapter:

> If a BEFORE trigger fails, the operation on the corresponding row is not performed

Although the scenario you describe implies that the data is not normalized.

Answer (score 1):

Besides constraints, you could achieve a similar result by **not** storing at all the x, y, z columns and using a view:

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
SELECT
    a, b, c,
    ( a = a ) AS x,
    ( b = b ) AS y,
    ( c = c ) AS z
FROM myTable
```