# MySQL `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` how can I skip data insertion under condition?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Trigger to prevent INSERT under certain conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981930/mysql-trigger-to-prevent-insert-under-certain-conditions)

In MySQL `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` how can I skip data insertion under condition?

```
delimiter //
drop trigger if exists test_trigger //
create trigger test_trigger before insert on t
for each row
begin
  set @found := false;

  #Some code

  if @found then
    #How to skip the data insertion under condition?
  end if;
end   //

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two solutions, both raise an error:

1. Call non-existent stored procedure - `CALL non_existent_proc()`
2. Use [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) statement to raise the error (MySQL 5.5).

Example 1:

```
...
IF @found THEN
  CALL non_existent_proc();
END IF;
...
```

Example 2:

```
...
IF @found THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Wrong data';`
END IF;
...
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this silently?

Comment: Use procedure with parameters instead of trigger, and add records after condition.

Comment: So there is no way via triggers?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way.

Comment: This is very disappointing. But still: Thank you :-)