# Directory tree in MySQL: any way to have both referential integrity and filename uniqueness within a folder?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to model a directory tree in MySQL, my first idea was:

```
CREATE TABLE Folder (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    parentId INT UNSIGNED,

    UNIQUE INDEX (name, parentId),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (parentId) REFERENCES Folder (id)

)
```

But due to the fact that MySQL allows multiple NULLs in a unique index, with this definition I could have 2 folders with the same name at root level like so:

```
id  | name  | parentId
----------------------
1   | a     | null
2   | a     | null
```

Can you find a way to have both of the following?

1. a foreign key preventing a folder from being the child of a
   non-existing folder
2. a uniqueness constraint preventing a folder from
   containing two files with the same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MySQL does not support check constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2115497/395857). One possible way to enforce such advanced conditions is to use a [before insert/update trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22489342/395857), and throw an error if the insert/update doesn't satisfy your conditions.