# How to prevent of giving vote to his own post?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named *Votes* like this:

```
// Votes
+----+---------+------------+---------+-------+------------+
| id | post_id | table_code | user_id | value | timestamp  |
+----+---------+------------+---------+-------+------------+
| 1  |  1424   | 2          | 433     | 1     | 1445898101 |
| 2  |  53431  | 4          | 54      | -1    | 1443891149 |
  .     .        .         .       .
  .     .        .         .       .  
+----+---------+---------+-------+------------+
```

Now I want to know, how should I check `Votes` table that the new vote is belong to his-own-post or that post is from other guy? Should I check `$_SESSION['user_id']` with what?

Comment: ...yes and with a `WHERE` clause. Plus, make sure you start the session.

Comment: Ofcourse just check the session id either equal to posted user id or not

Comment: Why do you let people vote on their own posts in the first place?

Comment: @Barmar I don't let them *(vote button is deactivate when people open their own post)*, But I'm worried about hacker. They can active that vote-button simple.

Comment: All important checks should be done on the server, not in the client.

Comment: @Barmar Well that's exactly my question, *How to prevent of giving vote to his own post* server-side. So, what do you mean of *"first place"*? Actually I want to do that before inserting.

Comment: When the user is submitting a vote, perform a query to get the `author_id` of the post they're voting on. If it's the same as `$_SESSION['user_id']`, don't insert into the `Votes` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for this when they're trying to vote, and not allow the vote. Do a query like:

```
SELECT author_id
FROM Posts
WHERE id = $_POST[post_id]
```

Then check if the author is the same as the current user:

```
if ($row['author_id'] == $_SESSION['user_id']) {
    echo "You can't vote on your own posts!";
} else {
    // insert into Votes table
}
```

If you want to do the check in `INSERT` query, you can do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO Votes (post_id, user_id, value, timestamp)
SELECT $post_id, $user_id, $value, $timestamp
FROM DUAL
WHERE $user_id != (SELECT author_id FROM Posts WHERE id = $post_id)
```

Then to report the error, you can get the number of rows affected by the query; if this is `0`, it means they tried to vote on their own post.

```
if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) == 0) {
    echo "You can't vote on your own posts!";
} else {
    echo "Thank you, your vote has been recorded.";
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, +1 ..! Just one thing, how can I use this query? what happens if user gives a vote to his own post?

Comment: Nothing happens except they get more votes than they should.

Comment: I've added some sample code to show how to check when they try to vote.

Comment: Ah, then you mean is I send a query for checking that before `INSERT`. Emm that's not bad. But I think two separated queries (`select`,`insert`) just for a vote is kinda unoptimized, anyway ok thanks for yor attention.

Comment: BTW, is this the same with yours `INSERT INTO Votes (post_id,user_id,value,timestamp) VALUES (".$post_id.",".$user_id.",".$value.",".$timeStamp.") WHERE user_id != (SELECT user_id FROM Post WHERE post_id = ".$post_id.")` ?

Comment: You can't use a `WHERE` clause in `INSERT`.

Comment: And my last question, Is there any difference between checking that using a separated query and a trigger? I mean is I can do what you said with a trigger, now I want to know which one is better? trigger or a query in php file?

Comment: Whichever you prefer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981930/mysql-trigger-to-prevent-insert-under-certain-conditions/22489342#22489342 for how to use a trigger to make the attempted insertion fail.

Comment: If you have many different scripts inserting votes, using a trigger allows you to put the logic in one place, instead of repeating it in each script. If there's just one voting script, I would just do it there, because you can then see the logic.

Comment: `... FROM DUAL ...`, what is `DUAL` ? Is it a real table?

Comment: DUAL is a fake table that you can use as a placeholder in queries like this.

Comment: Oh, very well ...! Now I have three questions: 1. Just `DUAL`? I mean is `DUAL` is a constant keyword? or any word can be an alternative instead of `DUAL`?

Comment: 2. Your query is better or this: `... FROM Posts p
WHERE id = $post_id and p.author_id != $user_id` ?

Comment: 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table 2. Yes, you could write it like that instead.

Comment: Well Just those two above questions `:-)` I understand the third o by myself. Also really thanks for your old answers and *(beforehand)* thanks for your new answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the check within your MySQL query. Don't forget to protect against MySQL injection. Not 100% sure about the syntax, but this should give you a good idea.

```
$answer = $MySQL->query("UPDATE Votes SET ['value'] = (['value']+1) WHERE post_id = ".$post_id." AND user_id != ".$SESSION['user_id']);
if($answer) return "Upvoted";
else return "Can't upvote yourself !";
```

EDIT :

You should actually do a check in your Posts table first

```
$userWhoPosted= $MySQL->query("SELECT user_id FROM Post WHERE post_id = ".$post_id);
if($userWhoPosted != $_SESSION['user_id']){
    $answer = $MySQL->query("INSERT INTO Votes (post_id,user_id,value,timestamp) VALUES (".$post_id.",".$user_id.",".$value.",".$timeStamp.")  ")
}  
else return "Can't upvotes yourself";
```

EDIT 2 :

```
$answer = $MySQL->query("INSERT INTO Votes (post_id,user_id,value,timestamp) VALUES (".$post_id.",".$user_id.",".$value.",".$timeStamp.") WHERE user_id != (SELECT user_id FROM Post WHERE post_id = ".$post_id.")  ")
```

Comment: `user_id` stores what user? who is owner of post or who is giving a vote?

Comment: edited my post, At first, I didn't get how your DB was structured.

Comment: Your solution after EDIT works ..! But 2 queries for inserting a vote does't seem good ..!

Comment: You could also do it in a subquery, I'll do another edit. But imo, that's still the best way you could do it

Comment: DONT make another query. Presumably, the author of the post's information is already pulled into that page. Just check it before doing the query.

Comment: Still I believe I can do that using one without another query or a sub-query. But thanks for your try. +1

Comment: @Pamblam The author of the post is not in the Votes tables, only the post_id and the user who upvoted/downvoted is.

Comment: When you're creating the page, make sure you include the author's user ID number somewhere, maybe in a hidden input field if security isn't a big issue. Then when the user click just do a simple conditional to see if it's the same id. This is super basic stuff and you have given no helpful information or code at all, so that's all i'm gonna say. in the future, please include code samples and be very specific about the question.

Comment: There is no need for two queries here

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give us enough information, but there is a classical solution in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE Votes
(
// your fields here
CONSTRAINT uc_post_user_vote UNIQUE (post_id,user_id,value)
)
```

It means that one user won't be able give vote up or down twice for the same post.
Think abobut this, I hope it'll help you.

Comment: `user_id` stores what user? who is owner of post or who is giving a vote?

Comment: @Pamblam How this is a great solution? It just prevent of giving two votes to one post ..! My question is, where should I store the user of author? in the Post table or Votes table?

Comment: if that is your only question, the answer is store the OP's id in posts, store the voters in votes. or whatever.