# How does stackoverflow find users to give them their notifications?

Tags: mysql, data-structures

I'm creating a website like SO. Now I want to know, when I write a comment under Jack's answer/question, what happens? SO sends a notification to Jack, right? So how SO finds Jack?

In other word, should I store author-user-id in the Votes/Comments tables? Here is my current Votes-table structure:

```
// Votes
+----+---------+------------+---------+-------+------------+
| id | post_id | table_code | user_id | value | timestamp  |
+----+---------+------------+---------+-------+------------+
//                               ^ this column stores the user-id who has sent vote
//                   ^ because there is multiple Posts table (focus on the Edit)
```

Now I want to send a notification for post-owner. But I don't know how can I find him? Should I add a new column on Votes table named `owner` and store the author-id ?

---

**Edit:** I have to mention that I have four `Posts` tables *(I know this structure is crazy, but in reality the structure of those `Posts` tables are really different and I can't to create just one table instead)*. Something like this:

```
// Posts1 (table_code: 1)
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | title |  content  |
+----+-------+-----------+

// Posts2 (table_code: 2)
+----+-------+-----------+-----------+
| id | title |  content  | author_id |
+----+-------+-----------+-----------+

// Posts3 (table_code: 3)
+----+-------+-----------+-----------+
| id | title |  content  | author_id |
+----+-------+-----------+-----------+

// Posts4 (table_code: 4)
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | title |  content  |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

But the way, Just some of those `Post` tables have `author_id` column (Because I have two `Posts` tables which are not made by the users). So, as you see, I can't create a foreign key on those `Posts` tables.

**What I need:** I want a `TRIGGER AFTER INSERT` on `Votes` table which send a notification to the `author` if there is a `author_id` column. (or a query which returns `author_id` if there is a `author_id`). Or anyway a good solution for my problem ...

Comment: Yes. And ten more characters of yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Votes.post_id` should be a foreign key into the `Posts` table. From there you can get `Posts.author_id`, and send the notification to that user.

With your multiple `Posts#` tables, you can't use a real foreign key. But you can write a `UNION` query that joins with the appropriate table depending on the `table_code` value.

```
SELECT p.author_id
FROM Votes AS v
JOIN Posts2 AS p ON p.id = v.post_id
WHERE v.table_code = 2
UNION
SELECT p.author_id
FROM Votes AS v
JOIN Posts3 AS p ON p.id = v.post_id
WHERE v.table_code = 3
```

Try to avoid storing data that you can get by following foreign keys, so that the information is only stored one place. If you run into performance problems because of excessive joining, you may need to violate this normalization principle, but only as a last resort.

Comment: Well thanks for your answer +1...! But I figured out that I haven't mentioned to the my exact problem. I edited my question. Please take a look at it .. *(I know, my problem is really hard, anyway waiting for your opinion about it)*

Comment: Added the query that searches multiple tables using `UNION`.

Comment: You are familiar with my table structure ... May you please take a look at [my another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363469/how-to-prevent-of-giving-vote-to-his-own-post), Usually just *you* give me a proper answer ..!