# MySQL table constraint with 2 values

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL DB I have a table that stores information about contractor's activities:

```
`task_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`task_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`contractor_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0'
```

Business logic demands that `task_id`'s 5 and 6 are mutually exclusive, and for any given date any given contractor can have only 1 of them.
Is it possible to impose some constraint on that table that would enforce this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think adding constraint will solve the problem. You can try adding a `trigger before insert on table` and check if for that `contractor_id` you trying to insert, if its `new.task_id` is equal to 5 either 6 you should get this value and `select` on the table if there is any registry that goes against your business metrics and avoid it to be added before the insert finishes. I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981930/mysql-trigger-to-prevent-insert-under-certain-conditions#22489342) simple explanation will help you go further this.

Comment: I was expecting that some complex logic will be required. Thanks for the link, that's exactly what I needed.