# MySQL test before insert and cancel if condition is met

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I would like to create a trigger that tests a condition before insertion and if the condition is met then cancels the insert.

I came across this code in the manual which contains if statement, but no ways to cancel the insert is specified in the documentation.

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 0;
    ->     ELSEIF NEW.amount > 100 THEN
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 100;
    ->     END IF;
    -> END;
```

Comment: This trigger is for `UPDATE` not `INSERT`.

Comment: I think the only way to block an `INSERT` from MySQL would be to throw an exception, which isn't very nice.  Is there some way you could block the  `INSERT` from your app layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a [signal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html)

> SIGNAL is the way to “return” an error. SIGNAL provides error
>   information to a handler, to an outer portion of the application, or
>   to the client. Also, it provides control over the error's
>   characteristics (error number, SQLSTATE value, message).

Thus you can have

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 0;
    ->     ELSEIF NEW.amount > 100 THEN
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 100;
           ELSE
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000'
                 SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Sorry cannot insert', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1000;
    ->     END IF;
    -> END;
```

Update: You might also want to take a look at the [error messages list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html) and choose a more appropriate error number.

Comment: Nice solution! But indeed, you do need a different error type. `SQLSTATE 01xxx` is a warning and doesn't cancel the operation. When in doubt, you can use `HY000`, which is the code for "generic exception".

Comment: The error is not triggered. I implement it using https://stackoverflow.com/a/31613668/717267