# reject mysql insert query in which particular column is zero (0)

Tags: mysql, linux

Server version: 5.6, memory 16G,8 core processors

I have a table "radacct" which is updated by network routers. the routers send insert query every minute randomly. example of insert query

```
INSERT INTO radacct(acctsessionid,acctuniqueid,username,realm,nasipaddress,
nasportid,nasporttype,acctstarttime,acctstoptime,acctsessiontime,  acctauthentic, 
connectinfo_start, connectinfo_stop, acctinputoctets,  acctoutputoctets,
calledstationid,callingstationid, acctterminatecause, servicetype, framedprotocol, 
framedipaddress, acctstartdelay, acctstopdelay, xascendsessionsvrkey) 
VALUES ('25', 'bv4545ae155701','batmanuser', '', '192.168.1.100', '991990188', 
'Ethernet', '2016-08-25 19:15:40', NULL, '0','RADIUS', '','', '0', '0', '', 
'55:6t:33:xy:59:9o', '','Framed-User', 'PPP', '10.57.16.0','0', '0', '');
```

Table schema:

```
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| radacctid            | bigint(21)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| acctsessionid        | varchar(32) | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| acctuniqueid         | varchar(32) | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| username             | varchar(64) | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| groupname            | varchar(64) | NO   |     |         |                |
| realm                | varchar(64) | YES  |     |         |                |
| nasipaddress         | varchar(15) | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| nasportid            | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| nasporttype          | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| acctstarttime        | datetime    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| acctstoptime         | datetime    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| acctsessiontime      | int(12)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| acctauthentic        | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| connectinfo_start    | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| connectinfo_stop     | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| acctinputoctets      | bigint(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| acctoutputoctets     | bigint(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| calledstationid      | varchar(50) | NO   |     |         |                |
| callingstationid     | varchar(50) | NO   |     |         |                |
| acctterminatecause   | varchar(32) | NO   |     |         |                |
| servicetype          | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| framedprotocol       | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| framedipaddress      | varchar(15) | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| acctstartdelay       | int(12)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| acctstopdelay        | int(12)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| xascendsessionsvrkey | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

the issue is that table field `"acctinputoctets"` and `"acctoutputoctets"` having `"0"` is no use to us and accumulated rows having 0 values takes large amount of space on server. I have no control over the insert query. How do i reject such insert queries ?

## Update

Before insert trigger

```
mysql> delimiter $$
mysql> create trigger blockZero before insert on radacct
    -> for each row
    -> begin
    -> if new.val < 1 then
    -> signal sqlstate '45000';
    -> end if;
    -> end;$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: are you asking for an alter table or to reject 0,0 entries

Comment: reject the insert queries with 0,0 entries for the two fields in radacct table

Comment: check constraints don't work. Insert triggers cant say "never mind"

Comment: The best you can do is in the insert trigger (the after insert), to take the id (the AI) and write it to another table. Then an Event sweep can clean them up with deletes

Comment: Maybe this post is helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981930/mysql-trigger-to-prevent-insert-under-certain-conditions

Answer (score 0):

## Create Before insert trigger

```
mysql> delimiter $$
mysql> create trigger blockZero before insert on radacct
    -> for each row
    -> begin
    -> if new.acctinputoctets  < 1 then 
    -> signal sqlstate '45000';
    -> end if;
    -> end;$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html