# MySQL create table check() with age counting

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, create-table

I want to create table with date_of_birth column and use check() function to only allow adults to be inserted in.
All i try causes: "curdate() cannot be used in CHECH() clause"

One of I've tried adding in CREATE TABLE:

```
CONSTRAINT `adultcheck` CHECK ( TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_birth, CURDATE())  >= 21)
```

Comment: I think its duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981930/mysql-trigger-to-prevent-insert-under-certain-conditions

Answer (score 0):

Check constraints aren't supported. You can write them, but they are ignored. Have a look in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

> - CHECK
>
> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Solution is to deal with it in your application.