# MySQL constraint for maximum duplicate values?

Tags: mysql

With the `UNIQUE` constraint, I can make sure that no duplicate values are entered in a particular field on a table. Is there a method for allowing only certain number of duplicates? For example, if it were possible to limit the max duplicate values to `2`, for the field `animal`, I could have 2 rows with the `animal` field having a value of `frog`, but any further attempts to insert a row with the `animal` field set to `frog` would fail.

I understand that I might be showing an embarrassing lack of data normalization skill here. I would appreciate any suggestions on workarounds as well.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use triggers, or you can embed the logic into the query itself

Comment: @coder001 Maybe someone should make a document for "How to Provide a Useful Answer". I searched, wrote a title that summarizes my problem, I introduced the problem (For which there is no code that I'm aware of because I haven't found any method for doing this particular constraint), I proofread, and now I'm responding to (non-constructive) feedback...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using triggers.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

[MySQL Trigger to prevent INSERT under certain conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981930/mysql-trigger-to-prevent-insert-under-certain-conditions)

Comment: Aha. I think this is what I'm looking for. Particularly, I should be able to use `SIGNAL` to find a way to stop the transaction as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8559284/1530115). My problem was that I wasn't aware of what triggers were for, so they weren't part of my searching. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`animal`) SELECT 'frog' FROM 
`table` WHERE `animal` = 'frog' HAVING 
COUNT(`animal`) < 4
```

Comment: There's some logic missing here