# Trigger Error MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, triggers

I'm having a trigger error its not executing the syntax seems fine to me

I'm trying to preserve the functional dependency dtype->skill

```
delimiter |

    CREATE TRIGGER htmlid 
    BEFORE INSERT ON Droid
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      IF EXISTS(

       Select dtype t, mainskill m from Droid where t=NEW.dtype AND m!=NEW.m;

    )

      END IF;
    END
    |
    delimiter ;
```

Any help?

EDIT: I've tried this and it still doesn't work gives a syntax error says check ur manual

```
create trigger foo before insert on Droid
 for each row
 begin
   IF EXISTS(
 Select dtype t, mainskill m from Droid where t=NEW.dtype AND m!=NEW.m;
) THEN signal sqlstate '45000';
end if;
end;$$
```

heres the error I'm getting for the answer by anonymous

```
stack trace:  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual thatcorresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' atline 5
mysql>
mysql>  SET @recCount = (Select count(*) from Droid where dtype=NEW.dtype AND minskill = NEW.mainskill);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'NEW.dtype' in 'where clause'
mysql>  If @recCount > 0 THEN
    ->      set raise_err_msg = concat('Error: <put error msg here> ', cast(dtye as char));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual thatcorresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'If @ecCount > 0 THEN
     set raise_err_msg = concat('Error: <put error msg her' at line 1
mysql>      signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = raise_err_msg;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'raise_err_msg' in 'field list'
mysql>  END IF;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual thatcorresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END F' at line 1
```

Comment: What happens when you execute?

Comment: I just get a Syntax Error

Comment: @AaronDietz ...

Comment: this trigger is doing nothing. Are you trying to update the table Droid?

Comment: I am trying to avoid an INSERT if there exists a droid in the table which has the same type as the one I'm inserting but if it has a different skill the insert should fail @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ

Comment: trying to preserve the functional dependency that droids of the same dtype->same mainskill therefore using a before insert trigger @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ

Comment: this trigger will not avoid an insert. If you raise an error then the insert will be stopped.

Comment: how would I do that? and also the trigger itself doesn't even execute due to syntax errors @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ

Comment: You can't reference your aliased columns in your `WHERE` like that (`t` `m`).  Also remove that `END IF;`

Comment: the syntax error is this `IF EXISTS(`

Comment: Pretty sure you're after this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981930/mysql-trigger-to-prevent-insert-under-certain-conditions/22489342#22489342

Comment: @RaymondNijland isn't that what I'm using..

Comment: @AaronDietz I have made the changes as per the link and it still doesn't execute- syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will raise an error if the same dtype and a different mainskill exists.

```
create trigger foo before insert on Droid
 for each row
 begin

 declare raise_err_msg varchar(128);

 SET @recCount = (Select count(*) from Droid where dtype=NEW.dtype AND mainskill != NEW.mainskill);
 If @recCount > 0 THEN
     set raise_err_msg = concat('Error: <put error msg here> ', cast(dtype as char));
     signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = raise_err_msg;
 END IF;

end;$$
```

Comment: "This will raise an error if the same dtype and mainskill exists" I think you misunderstood, if there already exists a dtype with a different mainskill in the table IT SHOULD RAISE AN ERROR if and only if you try to insert a droid with the same dtype BUT  a different skill than the one currently in the table

Comment: this is giving me an error in sql fiddle check my fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfd77a/1

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: I updated my answer to put mainskill != NEW.mainskill.  You cannot use sqlfiddle for triggers. Sqlfiddle is only for select queries.

Comment: I have tried the same query in my putty client and I have posted the error i'm getting in my post above if you could check it out Id appreciate it

Comment: this is the first error thrown ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'NEW.dtype' in 'where clause'
, the schema for Droid is (cname,dtype,mainskill) so I'm very confused @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ

Comment: I'm also getting an error msg : declare raise_err CHAR(30);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: `EXISTS` would be more efficient than `COUNTing`.