# SQL Database trigger |AFTER INSERT Delete records with the value of NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

So basically what i want to do is to delete columns with the value NULL after an Insert. My brain must be afk or something. Here is what i tried:

```
BEGIN
Update `table`

delete from test
where table.name is null;

END
```

or

```
BEGIN 

  DELETE FROM table WHERE (NEW.value IS NULL AND name IS NULL)

END
```

This is the Error Message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1442 Can't update table 'Test' in
>   stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which
>   invoked this stored function/trigger.

This only occurs when i insert the code above. I have nothing else this is the first trigger i implement in the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Trigger for updating same table after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Trigger to prevent INSERT under certain conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981930/mysql-trigger-to-prevent-insert-under-certain-conditions)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  "Deleting columns" doesn't make sense, and "dropping columns" is not something normally done to a table -- in a trigger or otherwise.

Comment: Sorry i meant records not columns

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Its no duplicate question.