# Unique varchar for some conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table:

[image]

I need make UNIQUE NAME if `CITY = NEW.city`

[image]

Blue - success. Row inserted...
Red - failed, cecause John with `city = 1` exists.

Comment: How add unique key for name with condition?

Comment: There's no such thing like a constraint with condition. You can add a unique index on columns `(name, city)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Trigger to prevent INSERT under certain conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981930/mysql-trigger-to-prevent-insert-under-certain-conditions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a unique key on NAME **and** CITY

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`
ADD UNIQUE `unique_name_city` ( `NAME`, `CITY` );
```