# DB for room entering limitation

Tags: mysql, database

I have making room that has `limit` of space. In this case suppose `limit = 100`.

And I have `total` that is when user join the room then `total = total + 1`.

1. If user join the room then check `total <= limit`.
2. If true then user can join the room if false can't.

So what I want to do for it in Mysql is

making before insert trigger for checking room is available before user join the room.

```sql
 CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `relay_novel`.`RoomJoinedUsers_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `RoomJoinedUsers` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET @total = 0;
        SET @limit = 0; 
        SELECT @total := total FROM roomjoinedusersInfo WHERE roomId = NEW.roomId;
        SELECT @limit := limit FROM rooms WHERE id = NEW.roomId;

        IF (@total > @limit) {
            // DON'T DO INSERT (HOW?)
        }

    END
```

My question is

1. How to do not inserting data into the database in before insert trigger?
2. Is there are better way to do it?

Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30137/comparing-dates-in-a-before-insert-trigger should give you an indication how to solve your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Trigger to prevent INSERT under certain conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981930/mysql-trigger-to-prevent-insert-under-certain-conditions)

Comment: @zedfoxus thanks! that helps a lot for me! but please help me about question #2. "Is there are better way to do it?"