# MySQL if statement trigger

Tags: mysql

Im trying to have trigger that when seats value is inserted is must be less than 31, the triggers doesn't work for some reason .. any help will be great as I tried other solutions but din work well

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER seats_check BEFORE INSERT ON booked
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
  if (new.seats_booked <=30)
  THEN INSERT INTO booked set seats_booked= new.seats_booked;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO booked set seats_booked=0;
  end if;
  END;
|
```

Comment: @Strawberry im usiing phpmyadmin to execute this query

Comment: didn't work? So an error? Unexpected results? Be precise? Also mysql-8.0.16+ has [check constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) as does [mariadb-10.2.1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/check-constraints-support/)

Comment: You cannot action the table which fired the trigger in the trigger (including inserting) - you can on an insert trigger adjust the NEW. values and that's what you should be doing.

Comment: @danblack  when data is inserted i get this error: #1442 - Can't update table 'booked' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Comment: @P.Salmon Can you provide better example or point out the mistake. i have a similar trigger that updates value for another table but that works fine . all I need to do here is match the seats_booked column to specific value

Comment: `IF NEW.seats_booked > 30 THEN SET NEW.seats_booked = 0; END IF;`

Comment: you cannot update the same table on which the trigger occurs. This is what the error message says. Your other example probably updates a different table. See [the examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) `SET NEW.seats_booked=0`. no inserts.

Comment: Alternatively, you could forget about the trigger, and just build the logic into the insert itself

Comment: @danblack sorry my bad, i get your point now

Comment: @Strawberry it might not work that well but lemme try to work on it

Comment: @AdnanAli good to hear.

Comment: @danblack is it possible to delete the record instead of setting it to 0?

Comment: @Nick is it possible to delete the record instead of setting it to 0?

Comment: @AdnanAli please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981930/mysql-trigger-to-prevent-insert-under-certain-conditions/22489342#22489342) which explains how to cancel the insert if a given condition is true

Comment: @Nick perfect !! thanks

Comment: @Nick is that possible i set trigger/constraint that will copy value of or column to another dynamically eg: the result from seats.booked to remaining_seats column

Comment: @AdnanAli possibly. I suggest you ask another question, I don't think you can give enough detail in a comment.

Comment: @Nick the question is posted already have a look  . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61307448/using-trigger-to-make-sure-inserted-data-doesnt-cross-limit

Comment: Looks like you've got a pretty good answer there already.