# SQL--How can I add a constraint based on multiple joined tables in an INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, insert, where-clause

I am attempting to limit the creation of a new record in a cross table to Active records in the respective primary tables.  In this example, the Owners table and the Pets table each contain an 'Active' column with a boolean data type.  The cross table contains columns for OwnerId and PetId.  I do not want the INSERT statement to fire unless both the Owner and the Pet are Active.

The unconstrained statement follows:

```
INSERT INTO OwnerPets (Id, OwnerId, PetId) 
VALUES (NEWID()
, 1234
, 2345)
```

I have seen numerous examples online showing how to insert data from a joined table using a SELECT FROM WHERE constraint, but that is not what I am trying to do here.

I am able to accomplish this constraint in my UPDATE statement, and I include it here in case it provides any additional insight.  The updated values are pulled from the UI.

```
UPDATE OwnerPets
SET
 OwnerID=1234
, PetId=2345
, DateAcquired='2021-01-23'
, CurrentOnVaccinations=1
, LastModifyDate=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
, Comment='My Comments'
FROM OwnerPets 
INNER JOIN Owners ON OwnerPets.OwnerId = Owners.Id
INNER JOIN Pets ON OwnerPets.PetId = Pets.Id 
WHERE OwnerPets.Id=3456 
AND Owners.Active = 1
AND Pets.Active = 1
```

I am attempting to do something similar with INSERT but nothing I have tried seems to work.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use select with insert.  If query from the two tables in this select -- no rows will be returned if where is not valid.   Like this:

```
INSERT INTO OwnerPets (Id, OwnerId, PetId) 
  SELECT NEWID(), O.Id, P.Id
  FROM Owners O, Pets P
  WHERE O.Id=1234 AND O.Active = 1
  AND P.Id = 2345 AND P.Active = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I applied your answer to my situation and it works.  With all the examples online showing this, I never picked up that it works for new data.  I mistakenly assumed it only took data from other tables and inserted it into another.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Trigger to check if both the owner and the pet before executing the insert statement.

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_active_owner_and_pet BEFORE INSERT ON OwnerPets
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
       DECLARE ownerIsActive INT;
       DECLARE petIsActive INT;

       SELECT o.Active INTO ownerIsActive FROM Owners o WHERE o.Id = NEW.OwnerId;
       SELECT p.Active INTO petIsActive FROM Pets p WHERE p.Id = NEW.PetId;

       IF ownerIsActive <> 1 OR petIsActive <> 1 THEN
           SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
           SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "your error text";
       END IF;
   END;
```

The NEW indentifier refers to the record about to be inserted.

The [SIGNAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html) statement is the way you can throw an error in MySQL.

(I recommend you check the documentation for your current MySQL version just in case)

Also, check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981930/mysql-trigger-to-prevent-insert-under-certain-conditions/22489342#22489342) that refers to a similar problem.

There was some conversation on SIGNAL statement and how to use it in a BEFORE INSERT trigger.