# Linked attributes same table

Tags: mysql

Good Morning,
I have a question, is it possible to insert constraints on the attributes of the same table when creating or inserting? Let me explain.
An example: if I have the Customer table with Name, Surname, Company name, etc., can I insert a constraint in which I have to insert either the Company Region or the Name and Surname but does one of the two information have to be there? Or also in another example: if I have field1 field2 field3 and field4, can I insert an automatic constraint that assigns field4 a value which is the sum of field 1 field2 and field3?

I hope the problem is solved, thank you

Comment: Perhaps this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981930/mysql-trigger-to-prevent-insert-under-certain-conditions

Comment: For the automatic summation of columns, you could use a generated column - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: Thank you, I try the solutions and see if I can solve it