# How to limit number of the many in a one-to-many relationships between two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL database with two MySql tables. First is with The first table (table A) has a column with unique values(from values (from 1 to n). In the second table 2 (table B), I have two columns: in the first I have a name and in the second i have values from 1 to n(if i ad an value in the . The second it's updated column in table B is a reference to the first and vice versa. That's done)column in table A.

My Question: Can I limit the number of aparation of times the values from the second in table A appear in table B, specifically to a maximum of 10 times?
An example is this: (with limitation for column val to 3) (the third table would send an error)

```
First table:      Second table:        Third table(imaginary)
+---+             +----+-----+          +----+-----+ 
|val|             |name| val |          |name| val |
+---+             +----+-----+          +----+-----+
| 1 |             |  a |  1  |          |  a |  1  |          
| 2 |             |  b |  2  |          |  b |  2  |
+---+             |  c |  1  |          |  c |  1  |
                  |  d |  1  |          |  d |  1  |
                  +----+-----+          |  e |  1  |
                                        +----+-----+
```

PS: Sorry for my english.

Comment: Sorry, still not getting the question. Can you edit a little more?

Comment: please review my edit.  I think we were editing at the same time and you saved after me, overwriting my changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a constraint to the table definition of the second table.  This way, the database will check the value for you upon insert and update.

Comment: Vary good (and funny) response. I tried to create a variable that counts how many times the values are in the 2 table...but if i make an update in cascade...than my variables are chaotic

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use a trigger: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints

Comment: @flix are you saying YOU don't work with triggers or you've tried it with a trigger and you can't get it to work?

Comment: is not really what i need....at that link, if I undestood correct, there you can test if the value is beetween 10 and 100...i nedd to count how many times the value appears and if it`s beetween 1 and the number i want(3 in the example) it` ok...else...error

Comment: @flix Your BEFORE INSERT trigger will need to SELECT COUNT(*) from the table to determine if the limit was already reached. Aborting is really the tricky part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538786/how-to-abort-insert-operation-in-mysql-trigger http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html#c8808