# How to limit a seller to add 10 products in mysql with their particular seller id?

Tags: mysql, insert

I need to limit sellers to insert 10 rows only in my mysql table with paricular seller id?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question?  How do you plan to use this table?  Also, what is your app logic looking like?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: A join will usually suffice.

Comment: Is that 10 on 1 visit, 10 per day or 10 forever?

Comment: 10 for forever...Its like for 199 Rs,you can ads 10 posts,for 499-100ads etc..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could get started here to limit rows for MySQL using triggers: [How to limit number of the many in a one-to-many relationships between two tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638850/how-to-limit-number-of-the-many-in-a-one-to-many-relationships-between-two-table)

Although, from my personal experience, it is a way better practice to place this limitation in your code that inserts the rows to the database than in the database itself. It will make everything a lot more manageable and eventually allow to change this limitation on a per-user basis.