# BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER on one table but insert should be done on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two tables say `table1` and `table2`.

```
fields of table1 - id and count
fields of table2 -  id and count
```

both tables have same fields. Now I want to create `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` on `table1` which will check `if count = 2` then insert into table2 otherwise in table1.

I created the trigger but when I fire this query ..example-

```
insert into table1 (id, count) values (1323, 2);
```

then one row is inserted into table2 (this I want) and same row is inserted into table1 also.

I want row should be inserted in table1 or table not in both tables.

what I do to achieve this ?

Comment: you want to fir the insert trigger that will insert into table2 only.and trigger get fire only after /before insert into Tbale1 which u have mention above

Comment: yes..that I want..if value of count = 2 then and only then row should be inserted into table2 otherwise no any action.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to abort INSERT operation in MySql trigger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538786/how-to-abort-insert-operation-in-mysql-trigger)

Comment: @Nanne Not Duplicate...READ CAREFULLY,,,

Comment: Please, don't use all caps. That is not really polite, is it? And while you're at it, format your question a bit, using the buttons on the editor. Anyway, you have an `insert trigger` on a table, and you don't want to insert something in that table. That means you want to cancel the insert. Another word for cancel is 'abort'. So yes, I think this is duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.count = 2 THEN
insert into table2 (id, count) values (New.id,New.Count);
ELSE
<<no action>>
END IF;
END$$
```

Comment: I am doing same thing but when I send count= 2 then it insert into table2 and table1.

Comment: what is your sql query and you doing insert into table1.

Comment: Here is my code..                                                               BEGIN
IF (NEW.count = 2 ) THEN
  INSERT INTO db2.table2
    SET
       id = NEW.id, count = NEW.count;                                                 
 END IF;
 END

Comment: Trigger get fire only when you will insert into table1

Comment: .....yes and this I want..I'll always insert into table1 but if count = 2 then insert into table2.

Comment: This I don't understand. Your question says cleary (and yes, I read carefully) `not in both tables`. This will always insert into both tables.

Comment: Can I avoid it or Should I think something different not trigger to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want this, so I suspect I might be giving advice on some sort of solution that should be fixed differently, but here we go.

As you can see [in this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538786/how-to-abort-insert-operation-in-mysql-trigger) it is not possible to neatly stop an insert. You could try and make an error so you'll not actually insert, but I think that is really painful.

What you can do is make a fake table `dummytable` and put your insert trigger there. Your row will always insert in the dummy table, but you either insert it in `table1` or `table2` according to your wishes. The meat of the trigger would look like

```
IF NEW.count = 2 THEN
INSERT INTO table2 (id, count) VALUES (New.id,New.Count);
ELSE
INSERT INTO table2 (id, count) VALUES (New.id,New.Count);
END IF;
```

You'll have to clean the dummytable now and then.

Comment: maybe you should post your actual problem. This kinda feels like the [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.