# How to delete content starting with regular expression in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to improve an ioncube cms with a hook.

I need an SQL query able to blank mysql content in a specic row in a table, but only if the content in question start with "Modified Product/Service - Username changed from to"

Just to clarify :

- the cms in question record a log with the old / new user password when a password is changed for a product.  I want to create a hook that will detect the line added in the logs, and then delete it.  ...or better : a way to ask mysql to refuse to save something if it start with "Modified Product/Service..." (i assume this would have to be done in php, but that also, i cannot figure out how to do it)

What's the SQL request i need for this?

Thank you for you help on this :)

Comment: Something like `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_column LIKE 'Modified Product/Service - Username changed from to%'` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE content LIKE 'Modified Product/Service - Username changed from to %'
```

Does the sentence really say `from to` like that? It seems more likely it would say `from OLDNAME to NEWNAME`. If so, that part of the pattern should be `from % to %`.

In PHP, you can prevent inserting the row with something like:

```
if (!preg_match('#^Modified Product/Service - Username changed from to#', $content)) {
    // Code here to insert the row
}
```

Comment: Is there any way i can ask mysql to just refuse to save those lines?

Comment: You can't prevent the insert in MySQL, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538786/how-to-abort-insert-operation-in-mysql-trigger. So if that's what you want, you'll have to do it in PHP, as I showed in my answer.

Comment: Well, you can make it blank the passwords with a trigger i believe? I suggest though that you look for a way to turn of this misfeature in your cms, because they really really should have a way to do so.

Comment: i tried with     DELETE FROM logtable
WHERE content LIKE 'Modified Product/Service - Username changed from to %'

 ...but it doesn't work.  Why it may not work?

Comment: I don't know. Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: Hi Barmar. Thank you for your help on this. :) Here is a paste on sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2bad   the cms in question is whmcs.  I want a quick way to whipe out specific lines in the logs, but leave other intacts.

Comment: Where is the data? The problem is probably that the pattern doesn't exactly match the log messages, so I can't tell what's wrong if you don't post some messages.

Comment: it's in the description field.  The pattern match (copied / pasted)

Comment: I mean you haven't put any data in the sqlfiddle, just the schema. I need to see the actual log messages, so I can make sure the pattern matches them correctly.

Comment: logs are looking like this :   (75430,'2011-11-21 17:46:32','Modified Product/Service - Password changed from to  JTYGHG?%gh','username',28,'77.81.196.116')

Comment: my query :    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblactivitylog WHERE content LIKE 'Modified Product/Service - Password changed from to %'");

Comment: That log message says `Password changed`. Your question says `Username changed`.

Comment: ok. it's working now with "DELETE FROM tblactivitylog WHERE description LIKE 'Modified Product/Service - Password changed%"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict in PHP you can use something like

```
<?php 
$question = $_POST['question'];
if (strpos($question,'Modified Product/Service - Username changed from to') !== false){
  //redirect to some page or exit the control
}else{
  //execute the insert Query here
}
?>
```