# How to do the Insert if the IDs shot exists in different Table in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Ok, Here is my table

```
Member table
memberID
1
2

BadMember table
memberID
1
5
memebrID from BadMember
Action table
memberID - otherfiel..
```

I want only NON-bad member can be inserted into Action.

So, if `insert into Action(memberID) values(1)` then the system will reject

So, here is what I tried

```
insert into Action(memberID) select 1 from Member where 1 not in (select memberID from BadMember)
```

But it doesnt works.

Can u help to fix it?

Comment: Use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, and signal an error if the row exists in the other table. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538786/how-to-abort-insert-operation-in-mysql-trigger

Comment: why we need trigger? the trigger is the last thing we should think of

Comment: @Barmar, I found. insert into Action(memberID) select 1 from Member where memberID=1 and memberID not in (select memberID from BadMember)

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought you wanted to prevent someone from inserting these row, not put a check into your own insert query.