# MySQL allow one relation or another relation, but not both for the same id

Tags: mysql

I have the following schematic

```
Book
    id INT(12), // PK
    title VARCHAR(50),
    isbn VARCHAR(50),
    price VARCHAR(8),
    image VARCHAR(200)

Book_Genre
    book_id INT(12), // COMPOUND KEY also references Book.id
    genre_id INT(12) // COMPOUND KEY also references Genre.id  

Book_Classification
    book_id INT(12), // PK + FK, references Book.id
    classification_id INT(12) // FK, references classification.id

Genre
    id INT(12), // PK
    title VARCHAR(50) 

Classification
    id INT(12), // PK
    classification_type VARCHAR(20),
    classification_description VARCHAR(200),
    classification_value VARCHAR(12)
```

Where `Book_Genre` and `Book_Classification` act as `join` tables from `Book`. Technically with this current approach a Book can have a Genre and a Classification if both `join` tables are populated with the `book_id (Book.id)`. The problem with this is that a book with a Classification is considered a NonFiction book, and a book with a Genre is considered to be a Fiction book.

I'm insistent on keeping the `join` tables as it allows me to give multiple Fiction books multiple genres, i.e. Action & Horror, and it allows me to give NonFiction books multiple classifications, such as their LOC numbers and their DeweyDecimal values.

Is it possible to limit a relation/reference to one table if a relation/reference to another table already exists?

To clarify:- I don't want a Book to be able to be given a classification if it already has a genre, and I don't want a book to be able to be given a genre if it already has a classification.

(Sorry for the naff schematic, not on my work PC)

Comment: This restriction can't be enforced in the MySQL database with a declarative constraint; to have MySQL enforce that kind of restriction, you'd have to add BEFORE INSERT/BEFORE UPDATE triggers on the two relationship tables.

Comment: I wasn't even aware those triggers existed until somebody posted it here - and it's an ideal concept, so thank you and to the other guys for bringing them up as they're actually really useful for what I'm trying to do! @spencer7593

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a **BEFORE INSERT** [TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) on each `Book_Genre` and `Book_Classification` table. The trigger would check if a relation for the `book_id` already exists in the other table and, if so, will [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html) an error.

The trigger code could look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_Book_Classification BEFORE INSERT ON Book_Classification
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Book_Genre WHERE book_id = NEW.book_id) > 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '90001'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Reference already exists in Book_Genre';
    END IF;
END
```

(Note: above code is NOT tested)

More info on [Trigger syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are, I guess, hoping to use a database constraint to enforce your cataloging rule that nonfiction books cannot have fiction genres and fiction books cannot have nonfiction classifications.

MySQL's built-in constraint capability is not sophisticated enough to handle your requirement in a simple way.

You might be able to build a query, and therefore a `VIEW` object, that omits genres when a classification is present and vice versa. But this would not prevent the creation of data that breaks your cataloging rule.

You might be able to build a trigger to enforce this.

But your best bet is to put a rule like this in your application logic.

Comment: I figured it would likely be a case of doing this in application logic, thought it probably best to ask. Anyway, I'll take a look at the use of `VIEW` objects as I've never looked at these before. And yes - your assumption towards the beginning of your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem (as it is involved 3 tables), you may write a trigger function before insertion into `Book_Genre` and `Book_Classification` tables which would check if any record with the same book id exists in another table and decide whether the record should be rejected.

It's a little bit tricky and you may refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538786/how-to-abort-insert-operation-in-mysql-trigger) as an example.