# Mysql unique constraint allowing single row for a combination

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

Is it possible to have a unique constraint such that one particular column has a value only once?

For instance

```
-----------------------    
name | price | default
-----------------------
XYZ  |  20   | TRUE
-----------------------
XYZ  |  30   | FALSE
-----------------------
XYZ  |  40   | FALSE
-----------------------
ABC  | 50    | FALSE
-----------------------
```

So in above table, for a particular `name` value, `default` value can be TRUE only once. And will have a unique constraint on name & price columns.

Is this possible?

Comment: Interesting question. AFAIK - You can't. But let's wait, maybe i'm wrong

Comment: @sidgate You should review the thoughtful answers given below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [*normal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) way to do this is to extract a separate table to hold the default price :

```
CREATE TABLE price (
    name VARCHAR(255),
    price INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, price)
) ;

CREATE TABLE defaultPrice (
    name VARCHAR(255),
    price INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (name),
    FOREIGN KEY(name, price) REFERENCES price(name, price)
);
```

Most people will advise introducing surrogate keys:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    UNIQUE(name)
);

CREATE TABLE price (
    itemId INT,
    price INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (itemId, price),
    FOREIGN KEY (itemId) REFERENCES item (id)
) ;

CREATE TABLE defaultPrice (
    itemId INT,
    price INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (itemId),
    FOREIGN KEY (itemId, price) REFERENCES price (itemId, price)
);
```

Comment: While other answers provide valid way to solve the problem, this one seems the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem with a strange aproch, using `TIMESTAMP` as a flag.

That`s usead as a "**deleted**" FLAG.

If IS NULL, then the register it's not deleted - Instead, if is deleted (<> NULL), the unique key will never conflict avoiding duplicate registers for non flaged as deleted registers.

For example in your case:

You will never have 2 rows with **default: NULL**, but you can have **N** with **TIMESTAMP** with they exclude time.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a trigger that checks if there allready is a field with the 'TRUE' value, and if so take action.

Note that you cannot easily "reject" the update. (see e.g. : [How to abort INSERT operation in MySql trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538786/how-to-abort-insert-operation-in-mysql-trigger) ).

You could for instance just insert it with false, and save your error somehow, by setting a flag.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a simple unique constraint over all three columns would not work because it would allow the following:

```
name | price | default
-----------------------
XYZ  |  20   | TRUE
XYZ  |  30   | TRUE
XYZ  |  40   | FALSE
ABC  |  50   | FALSE
```

In other SQL engines, you could just create a check constraint that ensures that for every set of `name` rows, the number of those rows with `default = TRUE` is <= 1. However, MySQL does not support enforcing check constraints.

In MySQL you could implement this via `insert` and `update` triggers instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `tableName`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

   DECLARE @sum INT

   SELECT @sum = SUM(CASE WHEN [default] = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   FROM tableName
   WHERE [name] = new.[name]

   IF (@sum = 0 OR new.default = FALSE)
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO tableName (name, price, default)
      VALUES (new.[name], new.[price], new.[defaul]t)

   END
END
```

And similarly for the `update`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround which might suit your needs.  Consider the following table definition and unique constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE prices
(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    price int,
    default varchar(255)
)

ALTER TABLE prices ADD UNIQUE idx (id, name, default);
```

In your app layer, when you `INSERT` records when `default` is `FALSE`, always leave the `id` column `NULL`.  This will cause MySQL to always add a unique value for the `id`, so that duplicate values for `name` and `default` may be entered (i.e. a `default` value of `FALSE` may occur multiple times for a given `name`).

However, when you `INSERT` a record with `default` being `TRUE`, you should always use the *same* `id` value.  This will ensure that a given `name` can only appear once as `TRUE`.