# How to have 2 way unique constraint between 2 columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to set a two way unique contraints in mysql columns ?

I have two columns like sender and receiver and I have set a composite unique constraint to these however, it only works if for example i enter 1 in sender and 2 in receiver multiple times and does not work :

if i have 1 in sender and 2 in receiver 
and
2 in sender and 1 in receiver

I hope my questions is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in MySQL. You can only have a unique constraint across multiple columns as you have seen, where you can exclude duplicate values of

```
sender=1, receiver=2
```

You cannot have a unique constraint that excludes the reverse of a constraint as well where if you have

```
sender=1, receiver=2
```

it also excludes

```
sender=2, receiver=1
```

Comment: Hi @davidethell So should i use mysql queries to verify if data exists for both sender and receiver before adding new data so there is both way uniwie ?

Comment: Yes, you could look up the sender and receiver before creating the record. Another alternative is to create an ON INSERT trigger that sends a failure signal to stop the insert. Try [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538786/how-to-abort-insert-operation-in-mysql-trigger).