# foreign key mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
PROFILE table {
user_id INT, 
apitype enum('facebook' , 'main')
}

USER table {
id INT
}
```

`PROFILE.user_id` is a foreign key that points to the ID in USER table, but only if `PROFILE.apitype =  'main'`

so basically `PROFILE.user_id` does not refer to an ID in the USER table if `PROFILE.apitype != 'main'`

How can I accomplish this in MYSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html) which is fired before insert/update and checks the value of `apitype`. There're even some ways to throw errors in MySQL triggers, e.g. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24/throw-error-in-mysql-trigger).

Answer (score 0):

Well, as this is logic, it should be dealt with in the application, not the database.

You can add the user_id in the profile-table as nullable, making the connection optional, and depending on which storage engine you use you could try triggers (not knowing much about them in mysql though).

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot accomplish this in an easy way in Mysql.

For exemple in Postgres you have a check constraint, where you can check if apitype is main then user_id has to be null.

In Mysql you can only do this with trigger and it's not so easy. I think the easiest way for you and maybe the most reliable is to check it in your application. But you can still set a foreign key on user_id even if it's null sometimes