# Filter null or empty input using LOAD DATA INFILE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I have some very large files (millions of records) that I need to load into a database. They are of the form:

```
word1\tblahblahblah
word2\tblahblah
word3\tblahblah
word4
word5\tblahblah
...
```

My problem, is that I want to ignore the lines that have no second record (the 'blahblah's'), like word4.

I'm currently using the following query to load the file:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file' 
IGNORE INTO TABLE tablename 
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(col1, col2);
```

This has the functionality I want, except that it still accepts the null values. Is there a way to skip the word4 type lines and not add them to the DB?

Intuitively, I thought using a WHEN or WHERE clause would be perfect, but looking through documentation and other info online, I can't find any examples where this would work. Am I forced to filter these records out before hand, or can I do it within this query?

Any help is grealy appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this by filtering the file with `grep` or `awk` and then piping it into MySQL (via `/dev/stdin`). Something like this:

```
cat your_file.txt |
  awk '/\t.+/' |
    mysql -u your_username -pyour_password \
      -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/dev/stdin' \
          IGNORE INTO TABLE tablename         \
          COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t'          \
          LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'            \
          (col1, col2);" \
      your_database_name
```

The regular expression given to `awk` on the second line just matches any line that has a tab character followed by one or more of any character. You might want to tweak it to fit your needs.

**Edit:** One other possibility occurred to me. You could use `SET` to set some magic value on columns that are blank and put a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on the table that will bail on a row when it sees that value. I don't have much experience with triggers but I think something like this should work:

```mysql
CREATE TRIGGER skip_magic_rows
  BEFORE INSERT ON tablename
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.col2 = 'IDSPISPOPD4815162342' THEN  # Some unlikely magic string
      # Trigger an error, which will cause the INSERT to fail†

      # If you have MySQL < 5.5 this is kludgy -- see Note 1
      DROP TABLE `Skipped row`

      # OR

      # In MySQL >= 5.5 you can send a signal--'45000' is a generic error
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = 'Skipped row';  # See Note 2

    END IF
  END
;
```

**†:** [Per the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html):

> An error during either a BEFORE or AFTER trigger results in failure of the entire statement that caused trigger invocation.

Then...

```mysql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file' 
  IGNORE INTO TABLE tablename 
  COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  (col1, @var2)
  SET col2 = IF(@var2 IN (NULL, ''), 'IDSPISPOPD4815162342', @var2)
;
```

Hope it's helpful!

**Note 1:** [Relevant blog post and comments](http://www.brokenbuild.com/blog/2006/08/15/mysql-triggers-how-do-you-abort-an-insert-update-or-delete-with-a-trigger/)
**Note 2:** [Relevant SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24/throw-error-in-mysql-trigger/7189396#7189396)

Comment: Thanks Jordan, this is similar to the solution that I ended up using. That being said, this is also what I was trying to avoid (filtering the data before feeding it to the LOAD DATA INFILE command), I wanted to incorporate this filter into the loader somehow. But if I don't get any other hits on this in the next few days, I'll mark this as correct, since as far as I can tell, it's the best way to handle this.

Comment: @Thomp: Added an alternate solution that might work out for you, take a look above.

Comment: The only thing I worry about with this second solution is time. Does it slow down the loading to perform these extra operations? I suppose the best way to know is to try out both implementations and time them, but I've already moved ahead in my development. Perhaps when I get some free time. At any rate, thanks for the solutions. A variation of the first one ended up working well for me.

Comment: Glad you were able to move forward, Thomp. I'd be interested to hear about the performance implications as well.