# Best schema for a complex relation in a database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm not an expert in databases, so this is complex for me but maybe it's no for a lot of people. I have the following:

`quiz`: Table which contains some quizzes

`project`: Table which contains some projects

`project_has_quiz`: A many-many relationship table project-quiz

`team`: Table which contains some teams

`event`: Table which contains some events (a project plus a date and some other fields)

`event_has_team`: A many-many relationship table event-team

Now, I have to assign an order for the quizzes for each team in an event. For example:

Say you have 5 quizzes `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`.

You create a project `projectA` with quizzes `a`, `b` and `c`.

You have two teams: `teamA` and `teamB`

You create and event `eventA` with `projectA` and you relation it with `teamA` and `teamB`.

Now I have to put somewhere that `eventA` with `teamA` must have a quiz order `a, b, c` and `eventA` with `teamB` must have a quiz order `c, a, b`.

What is the best way to do this?

First idea I have is to build another table: `event_has_team_has_quizOrder`, with a column `quizOrder` having inserted through programming code `a, b, c` and `c, a, b`. But I don't think this is the most pure way to achieve this and that this surely have problems of denormalization.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do

`event_has_team_has_quizOrder`

```
(event, team, quiz, sequence)


eventA, teamA, a, 1
eventA, teamA, b, 2
eventA, teamA, c, 3
eventA, teamB, c, 1
eventA, teamB, a, 2
eventA, teamB, b, 3
```

Comment: But isn't there any better way? I mean, I would like `event_has_team_has_quizOrder` `quiz` column values to be, forced by the database, in the range defined by `quiz` column value in the project related in the event. In your answer, maybe the only one possible, I have to ensure with programming that `quiz` column never is `d` or `e`. Thank you.

Comment: Good question. There's no current table that you could make (event, quiz) a foreign key to. Hopefully someone more experienced comes along to suggest ways you could go aside from using check constraints/triggers.

Comment: Thanks @chris. I'll wait and otherwise I'll set your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Even using check constraints/triggers I can't get what I want, because I'm using MySQL. In MySQL check contraints are parsed but [they have no effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-not-working) and, at least in MySQL, you can't throw an error using a trigger (that is what I would like to do), even if there is a [hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24/throw-an-error-in-mysql-trigger) but I preffer to don't use it because I consider it's not a clean way. So I think I'll go on implementing the constraint with programming code.