# Can a MySQL trigger simulate a CHECK constraint?

Tags: mysql, triggers, constraints

I want to use the CHECK constraint in MySQL, but it is not supported. (Unlike other RDBMS, it will understand but not enforce the CHECKs.)

I have seen some workarounds with triggers. But they tend to set a default value to the field in question instead of returning an error.

Is it possible to construct a trigger that returns an error if a condition is not met?

Ultimately I want a trigger that copies a CHECK constraint.

Comment: What exactly is your `CHECK` constraint? One specific type of Check constraints can be emulated by Foreign Key constraints.

Comment: it is possible to get a trigger to throw and error if the FK constraint is not what you are after. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24/throw-an-error-in-mysql-trigger

Comment: To @ypercube: could be something like
CREATE TABLE test
(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 number INT,
 CHECK (number > 0)
);

Comment: Well, if you make that `number UNSIGNED INT`, only 0 and positive values will be allowed. Is that good enough?

Comment: No I also need to check other variables than numbers, but it will some of my problems, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following syntax

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytabletriggerexample
BEFORE INSERT
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF(NEW.important_value) < (fancy * dancy * calculation) THEN
    DECLARE dummy INT;

    SELECT Your meaningful error message goes here INTO dummy 
        FROM mytable
      WHERE mytable.id=new.id
END IF; END;
```

Answer (score 16):

when you are updating data :

```
delimiter $$
create trigger chk_stats1 before update on stats 
  for each row 
   begin  
    if  new.month>12 then
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'   
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: only';
      end if; 
      end; 
      $$
```

when you are inserting data :

```
   delimiter $$
    create trigger chk_stats before insert on stats 
      for each row 
       begin  
      if  new.month>12 then
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'   
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: only';
       end if; 
    end; 
    $$
```

these trigger will work as check constraint ,work before insert or update and check month, if month >12 gives error .

Comment: Also after executing those statements, you should execute `delimiter ;` to set the delimiter back to `;`.

Answer (score 7):

From MySQL 5.5 onwards, you can use the [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) syntax to return errors from stored procedures such as triggers.