# How can I put a condition on a column on creation

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the insertion statement to fail if the the column `year` is not 2014 or 2015

I need to do this from the database side as a temporary mesearure until i can get access to the application code

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(345) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imdbid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4545 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `check` constraint

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(345) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imdbid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
CHECK `year` in (2014,2015)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4545 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE `movies`
ADD constraint checkyear check (`year`in (2014,2015))
```

**EDIT**

Based on updates from jarlh, `CHECK` constraint does not play well with mysql.
as per [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines

You can create a `Trigger` to simulate a `CHECK` constraint. Something like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg BEFORE INSERT ON movies
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (New.year NOT IN(2014,2015))
THEN
    signal sqlstate '45000'
    set message_text = 'check failed';
END IF;
END;
```

You can refer to the following threads for more information

[CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working)

[Can a MySQL trigger simulate a CHECK constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734920/can-a-mysql-trigger-simulate-a-check-constraint)

Comment: Someone said that MySQL doesn't handle check constraints very well. Do you know what was meant?

Comment: @jarlh - yep, The [CHECK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.  Trigger would be a better solution