# How define column a OR column b NOT NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, check-constraints

I would like to know if it's possible to create a not null constraint for either column `name` OR column `surname`. ex :

```
create table football_players (
    id VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    surname VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Sometimes we know the name or the surname but not both. I don't want a player without name in my database.

Comment: Answer to your question strictly depends on the exact RDBMS you're using. What is it - SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, some other DBMS?

Comment: @Andy Korneyev MySQL

Comment: You can't do that in MySQL - it still doesn't support check constraints (though it won't tell you that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard SQL method would be:

```
create table football_players (
    id VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    surname VARCHAR(20),
    constraint chk_name_surname check (name is not null or surname is not null)
);
```

This does not work in MySQL (the question was not originally tagged MySQL).  Doing this in MySQL requires a trigger.

Comment: You probably want to check for empty strings as well. For most people an empty string is not a "valid" name either.

Comment: Yes i tried that, but when i test it on mysql, i can enter null for name and surname.

Comment: @Robinson: that's because MySQL still doesn't support check constraints.

Comment: `DELIMITER // 
  CREATE TRIGGER trigger_players_name_not_null BEFORE INSERT ON players FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DECLARE dummy,baddata INT; SET baddata = 0; IF NEW.name is null and NEW.surname is null THEN SET baddata = 1; END IF; IF baddata = 1 THEN SELECT CONCAT('Cannot Insert This Because Age ',NEW.name, NEW.surname,' are Invalid') INTO dummy FROM information_schema.tables; END IF; END // DELIMITER ;`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support check constraints, but you can do something similar [with a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9734920/4794).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

You can ask if any data from PHP to load is null. For instance:

```
If (!isset($name)) {
    //code sql
}
else if (!isset($lastname)){
    //code sql
}
else {
    //code sql
}
```

and altering the table:

```
alter table TABLENAME modify FIELD varchar(40) not null default ''
```

or you can select IS NOT NULL:

```
SELECT LastName,FirstName FROM tablename
WHERE LastName IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_players_name_not_null BEFORE INSERT ON players
   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   DECLARE dummy,baddata INT;
   SET baddata = 0;
      IF NEW.name is null and NEW.surname is null THEN SET baddata = 1;
      END IF;
      IF baddata = 1 THEN
         SELECT CONCAT('Cannot Insert This Because Age ',NEW.name, NEW.surname,' are Invalid')
         INTO dummy FROM information_schema.tables;
      END IF;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```