# mysql Check if date is greater than 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I would like my orderedDate column *(using the date type)* to not allow null or 0000-00-00

I've set the orderedDate column as not null, but when using insert into

```
INSERT INTO Purchase(custName, price)
VALUES('Max Wong', 10.00)
```

Ordered date is 0000-00-00. I assume this is because it is the default value when no other value is given.

I've also tried

```
ALTER TABLE Purchase
ADD CHECK (orderedDate > '0000-00-00');
```

*(also orderedDate > 0000-00-00 and orderedDate > 0)*

And I read to try

```
SET mysql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_DATE'
```

But it didn't work.

I've seen a lot of php suggestions when looking online but I have to use sql.

Comment: If it were me .. I'd run a query to replace all zero dates with a "standard" date .. Even one that predates your business.  `1970-01-01` for instance  ...  Then you should mark that column as default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or something of the like.  Once this is completed .. You can simply use `WHERE date BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND DATE(1970-01-01)`

Comment: You may want to look up how to use a trigger in MySQL that works as a check constraint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734920/can-a-mysql-trigger-simulate-a-check-constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not support CHECK constraints. It parses them, so it doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't save them or enforce them.

If you enable the NO_ZERO_DATE SQL mode, MySQL gives a warning, not an error, if you use 0000-00-00.

If you enable the NO_ZERO_DATE mode *and* strict mode, then it gives an error.

This mode is the default starting with MySQL 5.7.

For more information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html