# Is there a way to make a SQL constraint for making sure only one row can have a bool = 1 for each unique StoreId?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, constraints

Writing the title is hard, so here's the issue.

```
store_id | supplier_id | supplier_is_active
A        | 2           | 1
A        | 3           | 0
B        | 4           | 0
B        | 5           | 1
```

I need to make sure that each store_id can only have one active supplier, and I'd like to do this via a table constraint CHECK. But I don't think it's possible to do aggregation within a constraint.

Any thoughts to a clever workaround?

Comment: You can do this in other databases with a filtered unique index.  In MySQL, you can use a trigger.

Comment: The second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734920/can-a-mysql-trigger-simulate-a-check-constraint) shows how to emulate a check constraint with a trigger.