# Constraint in MYSQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms, database

I have a table named **Groups** with `primary key = Pkey`. In Group there is a recursive association **Parent_group** references *Pkey* . I defined a Parent_Group as foreign key in relation *Groups*. I am using MYSQL.

Table bame: **Groups**

```
+------+-----------+------------+----------+---------------+            
| PKey | GroupName | Region     |  Role    | Parent_Group  |
+------+-----------+------------+----------+---------------+            
| k1   | RootGroup | Jaipur     |  Admin   | NULL          | 
+------+-----------+------------+----------+---------------+            
| k2   | G2        | Alwar      |  Admin   | k1            |
+------+-----------+------------+----------+---------------+            
| k3   | G3        | Jaipur     |  Guest   | k3            | 
+------+-----------+------------+----------+---------------+            
| k4   | G4        | Alwar      |  Operator| k2            |
+------+-----------+------------+----------+---------------+
```

Query for creating table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` 
(
  `PKey` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `group_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Region` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `Role` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `parent_group` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`Pkey`),
  KEY `FK_ParentGroup_ChildGroup` (`parent_group`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The `Groups` table will be shipped with my application with only one `RootGroup` tuple.

And `I want to impose two constraints on table?` as follows:

1. New inserted row can not have NULL value for `Parent_group` column
2. Add a constrain so that `RootGroup` row can't be deleted.

I wants to know, Weather it is possible within SQL (if `yes` how?) or I have to handle in back-end systems?

Can be use trigger?

**EDIT**: I wants to impose an extra constraint on table So that a new inserting tuple can not point to itself. e.g.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ("8", "H", "BOSS",   "8");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
```

**Should be fail**?

Comment: 1) define the field as 'not null'. 2) a trigger to disallow deletes on that particular record.

Comment: @Marc B : But what to do for `RootGroup` its value for `Parent_group is NULL`? Can I make it referrer to itself!

Comment: yes, point it at itself, but make sure you modify any recursive logic to detect that, otherwise you might end up spinning forever trying to find the root of the tree.

Comment: @MarcB : How can I disallowed in trigger? Can you bit explain more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24/throw-an-error-in-a-mysql-trigger

Comment: In order to avoid deletion of RootGroup you can create a view (with "WITH CHECK OPTION" clause) which excludes the RootGroup record, and then use that for insert/update/delete operations.

Comment: @Emyl: But  it will eat extra memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things about the two constraints you wish to impose:

1. New inserted row can not have NULL value for Parent_group column.

   - You can impose a NOT NULL constraint on a column only if it contains all non-null values. You need a null value in this column for the root node.
   - For this, you can use the CHECK constraint. Read more about the CHECK CONSTRAINT [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/creating-table-advance/create-table-to-check-values-with-check-constraint.php).
   - You can put

> CHECK ((peky= AND parent_group IS NULL)
>   OR
>   (peky!= AND parent_group IS NOT NULL))

This will allow a NULL value only for the root node and will enforce a NOT NULL value for every other row in the table.

2. Add a constrain so that RootGroup row can't be deleted.

   - That you have already defined a foreign key between `parent_group` and `pkey`, the database will automatically enforce referential integrity and forbid the root node (or for that matter any parent node) from being deleted. The database will return an error if a DELETE is attempted on any parent or root node.
3. For the point mentioned in the **EDIT** section, you can put a simple check constraint on the table like
   `CHECK (parent_group != pkey)`. This should do the job for you.

Read about how to define foreign key constraints and how to use them to enforce referential integrity. Also, go through the link I have posted above or [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/creating-table-advance/create-table-to-check-values-with-check-constraint.php) before you apply these suggestions.

Comment: The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engine in MySQL . [The bug is reported] (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25660)

Comment: [Learn here too] (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29170/restriction-on-self-referencing-on-insert-in-mysql)

Comment: Can you create a trigger on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` of these rows? You can read about triggers [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html). A trigger is always handy for advanced auditing of the database.

Comment: Excuse me, but it's Rachcha, not Rachana. I'm a guy. Good that you have found the answer. That was helpful for me too.

Comment: Voting up for your interest! Thanks!

Comment: accepting as this is the only answer and correct for other DBMS. Thanks Rachcha!