# Compilation Error in MYSQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms, database, mysql-5.1

Table structure is:

```
mysql> DESC groups;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| PKey         | varchar(64)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| group_name   | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Region       | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Role         | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| parent_group | varchar(64)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When i am executing this **Trigger** , i'm having a compilation error

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `group_before_delete` BEFORE DELETE
    ON `groups`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF old.parent_group=old.PKey THEN
        UPDATE `Error: deletion RootGroup is prohibited!`;
    ELSE              
        UPDATE groups
        SET parent_group=old.parent_group
        WHERE parent_group=old.Pkey; 
    END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

**ERROR 1064 (42000):** You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near ';
        ELSE
    t_group=old.parent_group
    t_group=old.PKey;
    END IF;' at line 6
    mysql> DELIMITER ;

---

Can you tell me what i'm missing here ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your IF statement, the following is not a valid SQL statement:

```
UPDATE `Error: deletion RootGroup is prohibited!`;
```

This should be this:

```
IF old.parent_group=old.PKey THEN
    UPDATE `Error: deletion RootGroup is prohibited!` set x=1;
ELSE              
    UPDATE groups
    SET parent_group=old.parent_group
    WHERE parent_group=old.PKey; 
END IF;
```

I have never done things this way.  It is a bit of an ugly way of doing it.  But if it works, what the heck.

Comment: I learn it from here: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Using-the-SIGNAL-Statement-for-Error-Handling/1/

Comment: Same is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24/throw-an-error-in-a-mysql-trigger in Mr. el.atomo's answer

Comment: You didn't copy and paste too carefully.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! ..But Why `SET x=1` ? We have not defined `x` ?

Comment: It's just to make a valid SQL statement.  Basically it is just designed to throw an error.  The following table does not exist: `Error: deletion RootGroup is prohibited!`, 'x' would be a field within that table, but obviously it doesn't exist either.  You just need that element to make a valid SQL statement.  Such as: UPDATE <tablename> SET <fieldname> = 1;

Comment: Rely now I can understood How can I throw Exception in SQL... Excellent TOM..Thanks!

Comment: @user1705796 This is really not the right way to do it. Read my answer.

Comment: @Jocelyn: But I am working MySQL versions prior to 5.5. So signal handling not possible...

Comment: This is a hack, so if possible use Jocelyn's solution.  Although I guess it wouldn't work with a MySQL version < 5.5.0.

Answer (score 2):

You get an error in your code because the syntax of your [UPDATE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) is not valid.

The links you give are 4 and 5 years old!
Since the `SIGNAL` statement is available in MySQL since [version 5.5.0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/news-5-5-0.html) (released 3 years ago), this is really not a good idea to use the hacks described in these 2 webpages. Instead, use the [SIGNAL statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html).

**Note**: From the comments we learn that the OP is not using MySQL 5.5, so `SIGNAL` is not available.

Comment: I am working with MySQL versions prior to 5.5. So signal handling not possible..thanks To answer!

Comment: OK. Next time remember (when relevant) to include the version of your MySQL Server in your question.