# How to create a CHECK constraint in MySQL that requires negative values?

Tags: mysql

I want to alter an integer column on a table to add a check constraint preventing the value from being zero or a positive number. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE example (id INTEGER)
ALTER TABLE example ADD CONSTRAINT chk_negID CHECK (id<0)
```

MySQL happily complies with these yet then allows the following:

```
INSERT INTO example VALUES (-1);
INSERT INTO example VALUES (1);
```

Are my constraints not actually being added? Is there a way to list constraints that have been added to a table after it was created?

Comment: This seems like you would need to handle it at the application layer, as MySQL doesn't support this feature.

Comment: No `CHECK` constraints in MySQL. You need to write a trigger instead.

Comment: @AgRizzo: if only it was a good way to terminate execution from a trigger.

Comment: @zerkms - I edited my comment to be more clear

Comment: Look at this question and the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7189396/2587724 - and flip that answer's logic around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's *not supported* by mysql (even though it accepts it as a valid syntax)

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that would work, but may be hard to debug. This is a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger AFTER INSERT ON my_table 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF(OLD.id <= 0)
   THEN
   DELETE FROM my_table where id = OLD.id;
 END IF;
END
```

Comment: To be precise - user may not have `DELETE` permissions

Comment: We can't assume he doesn't @zerkms

Comment: indeed. It was just a note that this solution may not work under some circumstances.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, thank you, but the effect is that data successfully `INSERT` suddenly disappears.

Comment: If the id is greater than or equal to zero it should be deleted, change the column names to fit your situation.