# Not null if other entry is not null

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am writing a table and I need A to not be null if B is not null (see below). I am trying to write a CHECK however I am not sure how to write it. Any advise is much appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE `Test`
`A` varchar(4) CHECK(?),
`B` varchar(4)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother with a `CHECK` constraint. According to [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> The `CHECK` clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

You can instead use a trigger, as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115641/535871). The test itself would be

```
(B is null) or (A is not null)
```

EDIT: Assuming you are using MySQL version 5.5 or later, here's how you can trigger an error signal when the condition is violated:

```
mysql> DELIMITER //
mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_insert_trigger//
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_trigger
    ->   BEFORE INSERT ON Customer FOR EACH ROW 
    ->   BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
    ->       IF (NEW.B is not null) and (NEW.A is null) THEN 
    ->           SET msg = concat('Error: Trying to insert a NULL A when B is not null: ',
    ->                            cast(NEW.B as char));
    ->           SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' SET message_text = msg;
    ->       END IF; 
    ->   END//
mysql> delimiter ;
```

(Note that I inverted the test because I want to test when it is violated, not when it is satisfied.) If you are using an earlier version of MySQL, you can use the suggestion provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9046539/535871) or [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180330233216/http://www.brokenbuild.com/blog/2006/08/15/mysql-triggers-how-do-you-abort-an-insert-update-or-delete-with-a-trigger/).

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind elaborating on how the trigger is written in full?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not enforce `check` constraints.  So, the only way you can do this in MySQL (using one table) is to use triggers.

I think the check constraint syntax you want is:

```
check ((a is null and b is null) or (a is not null and b is not null))
```

although it might be:

```
check ((b is null) or (a is not null))
```

depending on whether you really mean "if" or "if and only if".