# How to prevent using digits in a VARCHAR column using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `user`, and it would be queried both by user_id and username. whilst `user_id` is of type `int`, `username` (being of type `varchar`) should not *only* contain digits. The program could help checking the input, but I want to double secure it by not allowing purely numbers already on the level of the database.

How to make that happen?

Comment: use a integer type for user_id, so you can only store numeric data

Comment: @BerndBuffen My question is I don't want to have numberic data (in varchar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `CHECK` SQL operator. Unfortunately, this one is not supported by any of the MySQL engines.

There is a workaround, though, by making use of SQL triggers. You may find more information at [CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working) and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html

So, for me (MySQL 5.5+ required), the following snipplet worked:

```
use test;

CREATE TABLE user (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

delimiter //

create trigger trg_trigger_test_ins before insert on user
for each row
begin
    if new.username REGEXP '^[0-9]*$' then
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Invalid username containing only digits';
    end if;
end
//

delimiter ;

insert into user values(1, '1234');
```

The last `INSERT` statement raised an `Error Code: 1644. Invalid username containing only digits` whilst

```
insert into `test`.`user` values(1, 'a1234');
```

was inserted properly.

NB: Some kudos also to [Throw an error in a MySQL trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24/throw-an-error-in-a-mysql-trigger/7189396#7189396) on the `signal` idea.

Note that this example only protects against `INSERT`s. If you want to be safe, you also need to implement a trigger on `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **isNaN()** function to check the input value of **user_name**.

Click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) for read about `isNAN()`

Comment: I mean by MySQL system, is there a way the check it?

Comment: better ensure a validation on client side and send it server side.Its always good practice

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I mean I want to make it in database level (after programmatic checking; the client site can't even secure, a entry level hacker could easily modify the script and submit)