# MSSQL to MYSQL migration (check constraints into triggers)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, dbmigrate

I am trying to figure out how to properly migrate a sql server database into a mysql database. Everything went OK beside the check constraints (and on update cascade).

Is there any way or tool to automatic transform CHECK constraint into triggers?

```
ALTER TABLE customer
ADD Constraint CK_customer_Sex
CHECK (Sex= 'M' OR Sex= 'F' );
```

into something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER `CK_customer_Sex` BEFORE INSERT ON `Sex`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF SEX <> 'M' or SEX <> 'F' THEN
        END IF;
END;
```

Unfortunately I can't manage to get the trigger working with error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 5

Comment: I don't know mysql but you have an empty code block here. Perhaps you need to actually do something inside there?

Comment: You can't have an empty `IF THEN END IF`; even if you could, that trigger would do nothing to enforce the constraint. You need to "throw and error" in the if block; I'm not familiar with the exact syntax myself though. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7189396/4104224) looks promising though.

Comment: Your trigger also has a logic problem, this is always true `IF SEX <> 'M' or SEX <> 'F'`

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far, I need to dive deeper into the whole 'create trigger' thing here.

Comment: Given that it's 2016, hard-locking gender on `M` or `F` is pretty backwards thinking. Many localities are offering people things for "not specified" like `X`, among other things. Additionally this is a good opportunity to move this sort of validation to the application layer where it belongs.