# Using Triggers in MySQL to Update

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I need to use trigger to check my `Update (SalesQty <> 0)` but I cannot get it to work

```
  # TRIGGER - SalesQty has to be bigger than zero   
   DELIMITER //
   CREATE TRIGGER checkzeros BEFORE UPDATE ON Sales
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.SalesQty > 0 THEN
           CALL updating(0,'P10005',6565990);
        ELSEIF
           CALL ('Value Has to be Zero')   # not sure how to display error msg
        END IF;
    END//
    DELIMITER ;

   # PROCEDURE TO UPDATE 
   DELIMITER //
   CREATE PROCEDURE updating(IN SQT INT, IN PID Varchar(10), IN SID INT)
   BEGIN
    UPDATE Sales SET SalesQty = SQT WHERE ProductID = PID AND SalesID = SID;
   END//
  DELIMITER ;

CALL updating(1,'PR10005',6565990);  # some sort of recursive error here
```

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24/throw-an-error-in-a-mysql-trigger

Comment: Within your trigger, you are calling `CALL updating(0,'P10005',6565990);` which is the routine which is causing the trigger to be called - which is the recursion bit.  If the quantity is greater than zero then you don't need to do anything and let the update go through.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there's a recursion when you update the triggered table within the trigger:

```
IF NEW.SalesQty > 0 THEN
  CALL updating(0,'P10005',6565990);
```

Instead use `NEW.SalesQty` and `OLD.SalesQty`

```
SET NEW.SalesQty = 0;
```

Your logic looks strange at all. It says: If quantity is less than or equal to zero, indicate an error. **However**, you try to force `CALL updating(0,'P10005',6565990);` (quantity = 0) otherwise.

You might just want to `SIGNAL` an exception when `NEW.SalesQty = 0` or `NEW.SalesQty < 1`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkzeros BEFORE UPDATE ON Sales
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.SalesQty < 1 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Quantity must not be below 1';
    END IF;
END//
```