# Making a SQL Trigger that will not insert a row if it is similar to a row that already exist

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am creating a trigger that will happen BEFORE and the event is INSERT in phpMyAdmin.

```
IF(
    SELECT * FROM packageArchive
    WHERE EXISTS(
                  SELECT * FROM packageArchive WHERE 
                  packageArchive.item = NEW.item
                  AND packageArchive.pack = NEW.pack
                  AND packageArchive.weight = NEW.weight
                  ) THEN
-- Does nothing with this insert / Doesn't insert.
```

If you have any suggestions I'm willing to give it a try.

Comment: UNIQUE constraint/index on (item, pack, weight)?

Comment: Is `packageArchive` and `productsArchive` really two different tables?

Comment: No they were suppose to be the same, Thanks.

Comment: @OverBakedToast You want a Trigger to fix incoming data or a Constraint to raise errors if wrong data arrive?

Comment: So what is the problem with the trigger?

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza There is no THEN...

Comment: Looks like the best you can do is throw an exception .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24/throw-an-error-in-a-mysql-trigger/7189396#7189396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with the help of `@Juan Carlos Oropeza` and `@RuiDC` and `@Drew` 
My solution looks like this

```
IF(
    SELECT * FROM productsArchive WHERE 
    packageArchive.item = NEW.item
    AND packageArchive.pack = NEW.pack
    AND packageArchive.weight = NEW.weight
   ) THEN
signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'My Error Message';
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really are using one table, then use a unique index or constraint instead:

```
alter table productsArchive add constraint unq_productsArchive_item_pack_weight
    unique(item, pack, weight);
```

Alternatively, you might want a foreign key instead:

```
create index idx_unq_packageArchive_item_pack_weight on packageArchive(item, pack, weight);

alter table productsArchive add constraint fk_productsArchive_item_pack_weight
    foreign key (item, pack, weight) references packageArchive(item, pack, weight);
```

Comment: I think a constraint is very different to a trigger. Looks like OP just want to discard the inserted row, not raise an error.

Comment: The problem with this though is that I want it to store if only one item is different. That's the reason for the ANDs they're not ORs.

Comment: I did try this though and it gave me a syntax error
--  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`packageArchive` (item, pack, weight)' at line 1