# Error Code: 3820. Check constraint 'chk_period_of_execution' refers to non-existing column 'd_reg_date'

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS documents (
    d_reg_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    d_reg_date DATE NOT NULL,
    d_id varchar(255),
    d_date DATE NOT NULL,
    d_theme VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    d_description VARCHAR(1000),
    d_access VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 'Нет',
    d_control VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 'Нет',
    CONSTRAINT pk_reg_id PRIMARY KEY (d_reg_id)
) Engine=InnoDb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS correspondents (
    c_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    c_correspondents VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_c_id PRIMARY KEY (c_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_c_id FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES documents(d_reg_id)
) Engine=InnoDb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS delivery_types (
    dt_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    dt_type VARCHAR(14),
    dt_period_of_execution DATE,
    CONSTRAINT chk_period_of_execution CHECK (delivery_types.dt_period_of_execution > documents.d_reg_date),
    CONSTRAINT pk_dt_id PRIMARY KEY (dt_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_dt_id FOREIGN KEY (dt_id) REFERENCES documents(d_reg_id)
    ) Engine=InnoDb;
```

I'm getting problem here, I need to check whether the period of execution cannot be earlier than the date of registration. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A `check` constraint can only check values in a single row -- it can't even refer to other rows in the same table.

For this functionality, you probably need a trigger.  You can also use a user-defined function to return the value from the other table.

It is a bit hard to be more precise.  A `check` constraint logically ensures that the data is consistent *over all time*, not just when the data in the table changes.  It is unclear whether this is something that you only want to do when the value is inserted into `delivery_types` or when the value changes or when the value changes in the other table as well.

Comment: Where can I refer to? I've read that I can use functions and triggers?

Comment: [update-trigger-example](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-update-trigger/) might be a starter ... you can create a exception in the trigger => causing a rollback of the current transaction, like the constraint would do. [exception-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24/throw-an-error-in-a-mysql-trigger)