# How to create a trigger in phpmyadmin so that two columns are not the same suring insertion?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, xampp, backend

This is my table's records (already populated)
[table named *posts*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHGmy.png)

now i want to make sure that during insertion the **user_to** and **user_from** columns are not the same. here in the fourth record you can clearly see *user_to=3* and *user_from=3*

Comment: First, I'd handle this in the application layer first. (Actually, I do message myself on Slack when I need to test something, so I'd make sure you really want to do this.) Then I think you could just use a [`CHECK` constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html)

Comment: can you give a general code in sql for the trigger i should implement to satisfy the condition

Comment: Trigger **not needed**. Use CHECK.

Comment: but i need to use trigger its a requirement

Comment: Requirements are often not really requirements. My suggestion is to go back to whomever is requiring this and tell them that there is a better way, and that the MySQL team added a specific succinct syntax that matches your scenario exactly. If you get push back, see this for using a [trigger to raise a signal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189396/231316).